# need to remove xml nodes in a string and leave the text

Tags: c#, xml

i  have the string which is a part of an xml.

```
a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g
```

the problem is that i want to extract from the string the parts that are not inside any tags.
so i need to extract the string"aceg" from this string and leave the characters "bdf"
how can this be done?

Edit:
this was a part of an xml
let asume its

```
<div>a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g</div>
```

now its a valid xml :)

Comment: this was an html and not xml but we can make it valid by enclosing it in a div tag
so it will become.
<div>a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g</div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That string is not valid XML.

However, assuming you had a valid XML string, then you could do something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string contents = string.Empty;

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml("<outer>a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g</outer>");

        foreach(XmlNode child in document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                contents += child.InnerText;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(contents);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This will print out the string "bdf"

Comment: this one works but it works in reverse. i mean it extracts the string "bdf" but if u change the condition "child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element" to "child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text" it will return the needed result

Comment: Much better - its difficult possible to trust those reg ex's and with this you have a lot more control.

Answer (score 9):

The following regular expression will remove all tags from the string:

```
Regex.Replace("a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g", "<[^>]+>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: i tried this code and it will return "abcdefg" but i need to remove the text that is inside the tags. so i need it to return "aceg"

Comment: Actually what he wants is this to replace tags and inner text, so: <.*?>.*?<.*?>

Comment: Processing XML with regex is a bad idea. If those tags can contain attributes, or anything like comments, such an expression can go badly wrong.

Comment: Sorry, slightly misread the question ;) pauloya or grenade's answer will finish the job.

Comment: `<obligatory>` Now you have two problems. `</obligatory>`

Answer (score 1):

Following from @Stoo's answer you should be able to omit the tag contents as well with something like this:

```
Regex.Replace("a<b>b</b>c<i>d</i>e<b>f</b>g", "<[^>]+>[^<]+</[^>]+>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: this one works but i will go for the xml solution by sgrassie because it gives me more control over the elements