# Remove consecutive <br> from string using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have following string regex

```
"choose to still go on the trip. <br><br>\r\nNote that when booking"
```

After converting it with regex I need to replace `<br>` tags with only one `<br>` so string would be  like this

```
"choose to still go on the trip. <br>Note that when booking"
```

Comment: You have bigger problems than you think.... It is `<br />` (nowadays)

Comment: Could you explain the wider context? Why do you want to go from a string with two brs and a new line break to one with one br and no line break? I assume you are wanting to render it back out to the user. Maybe a good approach would be to strip out all the tags (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492131/need-to-remove-xml-nodes-in-a-string-and-leave-the-text) and then insert new markup (such as <br> tags where-ever there is a newline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to account for the case where there is whitespace between the tags, try the following regex:

```
myInputStr = Regex.Replace(myInputStr,
    @"([\b\s]*<[\b\s]*[bB][rR][\s]*/?[\b\s]*>){2,}",
    "<br>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This regex will replace 2 or more instances of `<br>` tags with a single instance, regardless of the formation of the tag (spacing, casing, self-closing etc.).

Comment: Again, this won't deal with br tags that are differently formatted - e.g. < BR>, which is valid html, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in another (safer) way, using **HTML Agility Pack** (open source project http://html-agility-pack.net).

It takes into account the various notations `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />` *without you having to worry about it*. This means you can focus on the actual task: replacing duplicates.

See [Remove chain of duplicate elements with HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307158/remove-chain-of-duplicate-elements-with-html-agility-pack), it explains an approach on how to replace duplicates.

Comment: Now you have two problems. Wait, that's what they say about regular expressions :)

Comment: @VVS: what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @L-Tree: While the Agility Pack is really cool you're throwing a full featured framework at a single problem, which might result in more problems.

Comment: @VVS: well yes, a framework designed to help you to achieve a task. To me this is simplifying the task using a framework that probably does a better job.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** If you don't know how many `<br>` you have, you can do this:

1. Split your string with `<br>` and remove empty entries.
2. Join the string with single `<br>`

Here is the code:

```
string yourString = "choose to still go on the trip. <br><br>\r\nNote that when booking";

var temp = 
    yourString.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Where(i => i.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Length > 0);

string result = string.Join("<br>", temp);
```

Comment: This does not deal with 3 or more `<br />` (and that 'version' too)

Comment: br came from user input and I don't know how many would be there.

Comment: If what you need is exactly just replacing instances of "<br><br>" with "<br>" this will work. If there are ever more br tags, or the tags are formatted differently (e.g. <br />) then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

like Martin Eden susposed:

```
while (text.Contains("<br><br>")) 
{ 
    text = text.Replace("<br><br>", "<br>"); 
}
```

or

```
string newString = oldString.Replace("<br><br><br>", "<br>");
newString = newString.Replace("<br><br>", "<br>");
```

do multiple such lines with increasing `<br>`

Comment: This won't work. What if I have <br><br><br>? The first line will reduce it to just <br><br> that then won't be caught by the second line. If you must take this approach, then while (text.Contains("<br><br>")) { text = text.Replace("<br><br>", "<br>"); }

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(<br\s*/{0,1}>\s*(</\s*br>)*){2,}", "<br>", 
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Replaces any two or more occurences of `<br>` or `<br/>` or `<br></br>` with a single `<br>`.

This takes whitespaces into account. `<br  >` would match aswell as `<br />` or `<br >  </ br>`.

If you remove the unwanted "\r\n" beforehand you can omit `RegexOptions.Multiline`.